# Find norm of $T:(\ell^1,||\cdot||_1)\to(\mathcal C[0,1],||\cdot||_\infty),$ $(T(\xi))(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\xi_k x^k,$ $\xi\in\ell^1$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

Let $a=(a_0,a_1,\cdots)$ be a fixed element of $\ell^\infty$. Define $$T:(\ell^1,\lVert\cdot\rVert_1)\to(\mathcal C[0,1],\lVert\cdot\rVert_\infty),\ (T(\xi))(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\xi_k x^k,\ \ \forall\xi=(\xi_0,\xi_1,\cdots)\in\ell^1,\ \ \forall x\in[0,1]$$
In the old exam I'm studying, we are asked to: 
(a) Show $T$ is well-defined and linear, and 
(b) Show $T$ is bounded, and find its operator norm.

I have succeeded in showing that $T$ is linear and bounded. To show that $T$ is well-defined in this context, would it suffice to show that $T$ is continuous? If so, I have already done that by showing that $T$ is bounded and linear, right?

The harder part (I think) is finding the operator norm of $T$. I have that 
$$ \lVert T\xi\rVert_\infty \leq \sum_{k=0}^\infty \lvert \xi_k \rvert \lvert a_k\rvert $$
But from here I'm at a loss. I gather that I should try to find a $\xi$ such that the above inequality is an equality, but I can't see a way to do that. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: To show the well-definedness, you need to show that $$\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} a_k \xi_k x^k$$ converges for all $x\in [0,1]$ and that this gives you a continuous function on $[0,1]$. The keyword is "uniform convergence".

Comment: for any $|x|\le 1$ : $\sum_{k=0}^K a_k \xi_k x^k$ converges at least as fast as $\sum_{k=0}^K |a_k \xi_k|$ when $K \to \infty$

Comment: @DanielFischer I would have thought that uniform convergence would be a higher standard than what you say in your first sentence. My understanding would be that your first sentence requires $\forall \xi\ \forall x\ \forall \epsilon>0\ \exists \delta$ such that... Whereas uniform convergence would require $\forall \xi\ \forall \epsilon>0\ \exists \delta$ such that $\forall x$... Is this incorrect?

Comment: @user1952009 I can see how to bound the operator norm from above  -- but I need to actually identify the operator norm.

Comment: @Cehrett The uniform convergence of the series (which is easy to prove) gives you the continuity of the limit function. You can of course prove pointwise convergence to show the existence of the function $T(\xi) \colon [0,1] \to \mathbb{C}$ (or $\mathbb{R}$), and then show its continuity in a separate step to show that $T$ is well-defined. But showing that the series converges absolutely and uniformly is the quickest way to get everything needed.